# Run custom bash functions with M-!

Tags: shell, shell-command

I have a few custom bash functions that are defined is some file and are made available to me in regular terminals via the line

```
. "/path/Custom Bash Functions.sh"
```

in my `~/.bashrc`. However, Emacs does not recognize them.

I don't really care whether they are available in any terminal emulator inside Emacs. I only care about them working when I hit `M-!`.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12229404/5091709) suggests setting `shell-command-switch` to `"-ic"` (adding switch `i` to the default). However, all this seemingly results in is that the output of all commands I execute via `M-!` are preceded by:

```
bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device
bash: no job control in this shell
```

I still can't execute custom bash functions. Auto-complete for them doesn't work either.

Maybe this is because I use a newer version. I use the latest version on the master branch of Emacs' git repo (pulled the latest changes and installed them less than 2 hours ago).

Comment: What `-i` does is to source `~/.bashrc` (assuming you use`/bin/bash` as your shell). So you can put your custom functions in that file, or source your custom functions file from there. That's probably a good idea so you can have your custom functions in a shell without having to source it explicitly every time. The complaints that bash issues however in the `-i` case probably arise from how emacs sets up the process and probably cannot be avoided.

Comment: Adding `-i` should work. Try adding `-ix` and post the complete output, preferably with a shorter `.bashrc` that reproduces the problem.

Comment: You're right. Now it works. Thank you. Maybe I simply mistyped my custom command or something in my init file or `.bashrc` was messing with what I tried to do. Anyway, it works now. However, there still is no auto-complete. I have to type out the entire command. Should auto-complete work? I tested it with `emacs -Q` and it behaves in the same way: The command works (after evaluating `(setq shell-command-switch "-ic")`) but it's not auto-completed when I hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Comment: Emacs behaved really weird today. I just figured out that that was because of these two lines that are printed. I use custom functions that run commands and work on their outputs. Because those two lines were included in those outputs, my functions got confused. I had to undo the change of adding the `i` switch.

Answer (score 2):

I just put my desired alias(es) in `.zshenv` instead of `.zshrc`, so that Emacs would pick up on the alias for sure, regardless of whether the shell was interactive. My main reason for doing this was because when I set `shell-command-switch` to `"-ic"`, I ran into trouble with the output of <kbd>M-&</kbd> because it spawns asyncrhonous subprocesses. For example, running `du -sh` on a directory via `dired-do-async-shell-command` (or <kbd>&</kbd>) yields the following output:

```
[1] 12345
100M    directory_name
[1]  + done       du -sh directory_name
```

As you can see, there is extraneous output surrounding the actual output of `du -sh`. This is apparently due to it running as an interactive shell. So I instead just gave up on making it interactive and placed my desired alias into `.zshenv` instead.